# Send Unicode request to web service using StringRequest class of Volley library

Tags: android, unicode, android-volley

I have some Unicode characters in my URL that sent using StringRequest class. Once I got them on server, They are not represent in correct format.I had same problem with receiving data from server that solved by overriding parseNetworkResponse method. What should I do for this?

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    // ...
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(
                NetworkResponse response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String strUTF8 = null;
            try {
                strUTF8 = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Response.success(strUTF8,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }

        public java.util.Map<String, String> getHeaders()
                throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Comment: what type of string are you trying to send?

Comment: "http://10.0.2.2/test.php?key=20893&rt=add&w1=تست&w2=تست" this is my URL

Comment: Those characters are not supported in an url i think. Try to url encode them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Arabic is a string, why don't you try this :

```
URI.encode("10.0.2.2/test.php?key=20893&rt=add&w1='تست'&w2='تست'").
```

Comment: Bad URL http%3A%2F%2F10.0.2.2%2Ftest.php%3Fkey%3D20893%26rt%3Dadd%26w1%3D%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%26w2%3D%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA

Comment: I do that by encoding just Unicode values and put in my URL string and works well.